# what is python equivalent to PHP $_SERVER?

Tags: php, python

I couldn't find out python equivalent to PHP $_SERVER.

Is there any? Or, what are the methods to bring equivalent results?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There's a lot of differences between Python and PHP. Python is just a programming language, whereas PHP is more like a web framework, as it has primitives for web related stuff. Like $_SERVER, header, setcookie. These are things that are not in Python's core, but rather in domain-specific modules. PHP was built to be a language of the web, that's why it has so many useful things for web programming.

Comment: Anyway, PHP is idiosyncratic, as you may access the $_SERVER superglobal even in CLI mode. It gets populated in this scenario too.

Comment: Well... Things are changing. Python is making its way. So, it's worth it to learn and build some sites using python.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using **mod_wsgi**, which I would recommend over mod_python (long story but trust me) ... Your application is passed an **environment** variable such as:

```
def application(environ, start_response):
    ...
```

And the environment contains typical elements from $_SERVER in PHP

```
...
environ['REQUEST_URI'];
...
```

And so on.

http://www.modwsgi.org/

**Good Luck**

**REVISION**
The real correct answer is use something like Flask

Answer (score 1):

You don't state it explicitly, but I assume you are using `mod_python`? If so, (and if you don't want to use `mod_wsgi` instead as suggested earlier) take a look at the documentation for the [request object](http://www.modpython.org/live/current/doc-html/pyapi-mprequest.html). It contains most of the attributes you'd find in `$_SERVER`.
An example, to get the full URI of the request, you'd do this:

```
def yourHandler(req):
    querystring=req.parsed_uri[apache.URI_QUERY]
```

The querystring attribute will now contain the request's querystring, that is, the part after the '?'. (So, for `http://www.example.com/index?this=test`, querystring would be `this=test`)