# What are good Python and/or Django deployment solutions?

Tags: python, deployment

For now I use some mix between [virtual_env](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv), [pip](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip) and [Fabric](http://docs.fabfile.org/0.9.0/).

This allows to:

- install required libs;
- generate dynamic content;
- isolate installation;
- push everything through ssh.

It works well, I just want to know if there are other tools around. The only problem I could think of is that it's a lot of to set up every time. It doesn't solve database / media files migration issues either, but maybe I should just open another question for this specific subject. Eventually, I don't know how to automatize the server setup. I'd love to have a tool to let me configure Apache/Lighttp/Cherokee and MySQL automatically.

Related :

- [How django projects can be deployed with minimal installation works?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313989/how-django-projects-can-be-deployed-with-minimal-installation-works)

Comment: What do you seek in a good deployment solution? Why is your current approach not working?

Comment: "deployment solution" is vague.  What is the question?  is it "I'd love to have a tool to let me configure Apache/Lighttp/Cherokee and MySQL automatically"?  Please update your title and question to actually state the question clearly.

Answer (score 1):

Fabric is the best solution for you. You can do everything you need using Fabric.